# Publish ASP.NET Core web API as self-contained project

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, publish

I have made a small REST API in an ASP.NET Core project, which I would like to expose to another (Java) application running on a Linux server. I have been told that this can be done by publishing the app as a self-contained project, and to me, this sounds like the simplest solution for my setup so that I do not need to install anything new on the server.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Follow this link [Self-contained deployment without third-party dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs156#simpleSelf)

Answer (score -1):

You can start by publishing locally. Set the API project as the start up project in your solution and click run. That should open a page with your rest calls available under the 'Help'.

Once this is running, you can call these from your browser (new Tab) localhost:[Portnumber]/[API]/[MethodName]?[parameter1]=Value1&[parameter2]=Value2.

To actually publish the project to your workstation, right click it and select publish. in this case to a local folder.

To set up your internal web site review IIS - Internet Information Services - this may need to be installed. Set the site to point to your 'published' location.

Once you have this working, publishing to a more public or internal web site will be easier to duplicate.

Things I quote are defaults, things I [Box} are values you get from your code or as in the [Portnumber] from Visual Studio's runtime.

Comment: But I want for the project to be _self-contained_. It should include its own version of .NET Core. This will not solve this, will it?